# how to fix "File format b'file' not understood. Only 'RIFF' and 'RIFX' supported." error?

Tags: machine-learning, split, wav

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMhgg.png)

```
f= open("my.dat" ,'wb')
i=0

for folder in os.listdir(directory):
    i+=1
    if i==11 :
        break   
    for file in os.listdir(directory):  
        (rate,sig) = wav.read(directory+"/"+file)
        mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate ,winlen=0.020, appendEnergy = False)
        covariance = np.cov(np.matrix.transpose(mfcc_feat))
        mean_matrix = mfcc_feat.mean(0)
        feature = (mean_matrix , covariance , i)
        pickle.dump(feature , f)

f.close()
```

this code the wav.read is unable to be proccessed and the error is occured.

Answer (score 0):

Well the question I hope you are asking is that the audio file you are storing isn’t supported by scipy and you are stuck there. That has its answer later in this post.

Now looking at the issue in your stacktrace, the problem is that you are not submiiting the actual file to the wav.open() function but the string “/file”, hence the **ValueError**. To fix that make sure you are storing the right string in the **file** variable.

Now about the file format error which I talked about earlier.Basically **scipy.io** doesn't support the wav file you are opening, I found a simple solution to this, by converting the file to wav using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis). Execute this command in the Command Prompt:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi output.wav
```

This will store your file in the output.wav in a format readable by scipy.wav. You could run this for each file beforehand or in the loop using subprocess from os library of Python. That will be something like:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["powershell", "ffmpeg -i input.avi output.wav"], shell=True)
```